# String formatting throwing error - python

Tags: python, unix, python-2.7, format

I find the behaviour strange. My code works in Eclipse-Pydev , but doesn't work in Unix . Can someone please advise wehere I am going wrong?

**Code**

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    def myDisplay(Message,File):
        print "Message",Message
        print len(Message)
        print "File",File
        print "**",'{:^48}'.format(Message),"**"
        print "**",'{:^48}'.format(File),"**"
myDisplay('Success','ABC.2013-07-05_00:00:00.txt')
```

**Error in Unix**

```
Message Success
7
File ABC.2013-07-05_00:00:00.txt
**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DailyCheck.py", line 8, in <module>
    myDisplay('Success','ABC.2013-07-05_00:00:00.txt')
  File "DailyCheck.py", line 6, in myDisplay
    print "**",'{:^48}'.format(Message),"**"
ValueError: zero length field name in format
```

**Output in Eclipse-Pydev**

```
Message Success
7
File ABC.2013-07-05_00:00:00.txt
**                     Success                      **
**           ABC.2013-07-05_00:00:00.txt            **
```

I am confused where I am going wrong. Field name in format is not zero length , why does it throw the error then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running it under 2.6, which *requires* the positional argument even if there's only one.

```
print "**", '{0:^48}'.format(Message), "**"
```

Comment: The positional argument for a single parameter can be omitted from 2.7 onwards.